# Reverse binary representation of int (only significant bits)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a program for reversing numbers in binary. For instance, the binary representation of 13 is 1101, and reversing it gives 1011, which corresponds to number 11 right?

Here's my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number");
    int numb = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int reverse = 0;
    while (numb > 0)
    {
        int rem = numb % 10;
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + rem;
        numb = numb / 10;

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Reverse number={0}", reverse);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

By this code I only get the numbers to reverse (13 -> 31)...

The input should contain a single line with an integer **N, 1≤N≤1000000000** and I want my output in one line with one integer, the number I want to get by reversing the binary representation of **N**.

Comment: "By this code I only get the numbers to reverse..." - Yes, because you're using 10 everywhere, which means you're getting the decimal digits, not the binary ones...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like that

```
// 13 = 1101b
int value = 13;

// 11 = 1011b
int result = Convert.ToInt32(new String(
        Convert.ToString(value, 2)
        .Reverse()
        .ToArray()), 2);
```

Explanation:

- `Convert.ToString(value, 2)` returns value in *binary* representation (`"1101"`)
- `Reverse().ToArray()` - reverse the string (`'1','0','1','1'`) as sequence of characters and converts to array `char[]`.
- `new String(...)` constructs string `"1011"` from array of `char`
- finally, `Convert.ToInt32(..., 2)` convert binary representation back to `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToString` and `Convert.ToInt32` methods, where 2 means binary:

```
int numb = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var reversedString = Convert.ToString(numb, 2).ReverseString();
var result = Convert.ToInt32(reversedString, 2);

...

public static string ReverseString(this string s)
{
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun excercise would be doing this without using the `string` conversion.

I have very little experience with bit twiddling so there is probably a faster and better way of doing this, but this seems to work:

```
 public static IEnumerable<bool> ToBinary(this int n)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
     {
         yield return (n & (1 << i)) != 0;
     }
 }

 public static int ToInt(this IEnumerable<bool> b)
 {
     var n = 0;
     var counter = 0;

     foreach (var i in b.Trim().Take(32))
     {
         n = n | (i ? 1 : 0) << counter;
         counter++
     }

     return n;
 }

 private static IEnumerable<bool> Trim(this IEnumerable<bool> list)
 {
     bool trim = true;

     foreach (var i in list)
     {
         if (i)
         {
             trim = false;
         }

         if (!trim)
         {
             yield return i;
         }
     }
 }
```

And now you'd call it like this:

```
var reversed = n.ToBinary().Reverse().ToInt();
```